# Как создать playlist в MediaPlayer Android?

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Как создать плейлист для воспроизведения нескольких треков через MediaPlayer?

В папке raw имеем три песни mp3.

1. как их воспроизводить подряд? То есть, чтобы после окончания одной песни начиналась другая.
2. Как создать случайное воспроизведение?

Скиньте, пожалуйста, примерный код или ссылки.

Спасибо всем кто ответил.

подскажите пожалуйста есть ли попроще код.
например такой.
Но к сожалению у меня не работает(
Как доходит до 3 трека приложение крашится.
заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

```
MediaPlayer song0, song1, song2;
Button play, next;
ArrayList<MediaPlayer> music = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
int track = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    song0 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.vr2);
    song1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.vr3);
    song2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.vr4);

    music.add(song0);
    music.add(song1);
    music.add(song2);

    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            music.get(track).start();
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            music.get(track).stop();
            music.get(track).release();
            track ++;
            if (track ==3)
                track = 0;

            music.get(track).start();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
ContentValues mInserts = new ContentValues();
        mInserts.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, mPrefs.getString(AM.MEDIASTORECHANGE_NEWPLAYLISTNAME, "New Playlist"));
        mInserts.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        mInserts.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATE_MODIFIED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        mUri = mCR.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, mInserts);
        if (mUri != null) {
            mPlaylistId = -1;
            mResult = FM.SUCCESS;
            c = mCR.query(mUri, PROJECTION_PLAYLIST, null, null, null);
            if (c != null) {
                // Save the newly created ID so it can be selected.  Names are allowed to be duplicated,
                // but IDs can never be.
                mPlaylistId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID));
                c.close();
            }
            if (DBG.AUDIO) {
                Log.d(TAG, "PLAYLIST_ADD - mPlaylistId: " + mPlaylistId 
                        + "  mSelectString: " + mSelectString + "  mUri: "+ mUri.toString());
            }

        }

public static final String[] PROJECTION_PLAYLIST = new String[] {
    MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME,
    MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATA
};
```

Полезные ссылки:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969281/how-to-create-a-new-playlist-using-contentresolver
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182937/android-create-playlist